# Python csv to json pretty print

Tags: python, json, csv, pretty-print

I'm having a few problems with converting a csv file to a json file using Python. Mainly in getting it formatted the way I want, like the following:

```
[{'foo':'bar', 'foobar':'baz'},
{'foo':'bar', 'foobar':'baz'},
...
{'foo':'bar', 'foobar':'baz'}]
```

Originally I had this for my conversion:

```
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(infile.csv, 'r'))
json_file = open(outfile.json, 'w')
json_file.write('[')
for row in csv_file:
    json.dump(row, json_file)
    json_file.write(',\n')
json_file.write(']')
json_file.close()
```

This gives me the desired look, but the problem with this is that it adds a comma at the end of the final json object, which creates an invalid json file.

I then tried loading the csv data into a list first and then dumping that:

```
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(infile.csv, 'r'))
json_file = open(outfile.json, 'w')
data = []
for row in csv_file:
    data.append(row)
json.dump(data, json_file, indent=0)
json_file.close()
```

While this method gave me a valid format, it also gave me a file looking like this:

```
[
{
'foo':'bar',
'foobar':'baz'
},
{
'foo':'bar',
'foobar':'baz'
},
...
{
'foo':'bar',
'foobar':'baz'
}
]
```

Only problem with that is it isn't very pretty. Any suggestions on how I can get the formatting like the first example?

Comment: what's wrong with `json.dump` ?

Comment: nothing is, the problem is that I'm unable to use it get my json file to look how I want. If you look above I used `json.dump` in both of my examples, but I'm having trouble getting it the way I want. Ideally if I could read the csv line by line like the first example and get rid of the last comma I would be set.

Comment: in that case, issue the comma line first (with a flag preventing it at first iteration). That's pretty basic.

Comment: ...wow I feel dumb that I didn't think of that now. It's been a long day lol. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: you're welcome. nice if it solves your problem. I don't want to answer something like that because I feel that it wouldn't help too many other people, but at least you get your solution.

Comment: yup, worked perfectly. Simple solutions to simple problems. Thanks again!